# express gateway не работает команда eg в консоли?

Tags: node.js, express, командная-строка, консоль

Установил [express-gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io/) и глобально и локально, но команда eg gateway create не является внутренней или внешней командой. В переменные среды добавлял пути

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пожалуйста помогите **что именно надо добавить, и что я делаю не так?**

Comment: У Вас в Path после `AppData/Roaming/npm` куда-то подевалась точка с запятой.

Comment: @Yaant Ох, вот я туплю, спасибо, я добавлял просто путь, а надо было в PATH. Добавьте свой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту, путь к `npm` оказался некорректно прописан в `Path` — между ним и следующим элементом отсутствует символ `;`. Из-за этого система и не может отыскать расположенные в нем исполняемые файлы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь